# If result not doing what i am telling

Tags: php, mysql

Probably something small, but i wanted to ask u guys.. i'm quickly writing something super simple. but it does not do what i ask it to do.. I am using the following query where frusr = 13 and userid = 13..

```
    $selectMessage = $db->query("Select `subject`, `content`, `frusr`, `to
     From `messages` Where `id`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['id'])."'
     AND `to`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userid)."' 
OR `frusr`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userid)."'"); 

if($userid != $fetch['frusr']){ // content }
```

the content between the if, just simply won't show up.. if both are same to each other..

Lol i swear its simple but i dont know maybe to tired ;p

Comment: are you sure you don't want to include ( ) to your SQL query, when you have an AND and an OR?

Comment: Well, you've got `!=` in your if, which explains why "just simply won't show up...if both are same to each other". But please provide a more complete code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use parentheses and the query should be as

```
$selectMessage = $db->query("Select `subject`, `content`, `frusr`, `to` From `messages` 
                            Where `id`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['id'])."' 
                           AND  
                           ( 
                              `to`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userid)."' 
                              OR `frusr`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userid)."'
                            )");
```

Comment: Thanks that definitly solved it.. will apply it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess... `$fetch['frusr']` is `NULL`? In code snippet you provided you don't set `$fetch`.

Also, please provide more information about desired output and what exactly do you mean by "won't show".

Comment: frusr can't be null, the output if i fetch it is 13.. just as the userid var is 13.  simply want an if that if userid is not same as frusr, show content

Comment: @KevinH show your full code containing everything between SQL query and if. Because, as I said, in what I see, `$fetch` is not set.